# How to align the Radio button, AutoComplete and Input Base in one row

Tags: reactjs, flexbox, material-ui, grid, styles

This is how my code looks like. I want the display to be "Watch Movie Yes I agree" in one line/row. How can I achieve the same ?

https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-diffie-5fzobp?file=/src/App.js

```
<Box padding={1}>
      <FormControl>
        <RadioGroup>
          <FormControlLabel
            value="targetSlump"
            control={<Radio color="primary" size="small" />}
            label="Watch Movie"
          />
          <Autocomplete
            disablePortal
            id="combo-box-demo"
            renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label={'Yes'} />}
          />
          <InputBase value={'I AGREE'} />
          <FormControlLabel
            value="false"
            control={<Radio color="primary" size="small" />}
            label="Do not show this"
          />
        </RadioGroup>
      </FormControl>
    </Box>
  );
```

Comment: can you add a codesandbox?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-diffie-5fzobp?file=/src/App.js

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `flex` and `flexDirection: "row"` to style your `RadioGroup` in order to align items horizontally.

```
    <RadioGroup
      style={{
        display: "flex",
        alignItems: "flex-start",
        flexDirection: "row"
      }}
    >
      <FormControlLabel
        value="targetSlump"
        control={<Radio color="primary" size="small" />}
        label="Watch Movie"
      />
      <Autocomplete
        disablePortal
        id="combo-box-demo"
        renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label={"Yes"} />}
      />
      <InputBase value={"I AGREE"} />
      <FormControlLabel
        value="false"
        control={<Radio color="primary" size="small" />}
        label="Do not show this"
      />
    </RadioGroup>
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-golick-g2ro2b)